# Oracle APEX Tab Container row too long and not breaking

Tags: css, oracle-apex, tabcontainer, oracle-apex21.2

My APEX Tabs Container has many tabs and it's not showing all of them in the page, forcing the user to scroll sideways to be able to see everything. There are no explicit options in the developer page that allows to change the amount of tabs shown in a single line or to wrap it.
[image]
Currently there are 26 tabs inside this cointainer, with 23 being shown and 3 hidden.

Is there a way to break the Tab Container "line"?

Answer (score 0):

The way I found to break the tab container line was to change a particular attribute inside the `<ul>` parent attribute that has the tabs, as follows:

[image]

By adding changing the `white-space:nowrap;` attribute to `white-space:pre-wrap;`, it breaks the tabs container line and allows for the 3 remaining  tabs to be shown on a second line:

[image]

[image]